# MVC6 Web API - How to deploy

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I downloaded and installed the RTM of VS 2015, got my Web API project working nicely, can hit F5 all works in IIS Express, lovely. But now I go to deploy my WebAPI on a local network server and oh my! I was hoping to find the publish to File System option and then to be allowed to select IIS but it ain't there. Publish to file system is there but that compiles wwwroot and approot folders and for the life of me I haven't been able to get them's files to run under IIS - tried all sorts, ege approot as my website root on IIS, wwwroot as my website root. I've found plenty of reference to show you how to deploy Web API ASP 5 to Azure but have as yet been unable to locate any information for how to deploy to IIS on network.

Answer (score 2):

Just got it to work, for the sour down voter here's how

1. Right click WebAPi project select Publish
2. Profile -> Select File System
3. Connection Target Location browse to somewhere that makes sense eg. C:\inetpub\WebAPI
4. Settings ->Configuration select Release
   Settings Target DNX Version select x64 example dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0.beta4
5. In IIS set the Physical Path of your website to be C:\Inetpub\WebAPI\wwwroot
   Test eg localhost/api/Values

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings :-)